# FileNotFoundException when reading a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm trying to crop an image received from a form upload. Before I crop it I save it, then I retrieve it again as a `BufferedImage` (because I don't know how to turn a part into a buffered Image). I then crop this image, but when I try to save it again I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` (access denied)

The first image gets saved correctly, I get the exception when I try to pull it back.

Is it possible to turn my part into a buffered image and then save it? Instead of doing double work. or else is there some fix to my below code.

```
String savePath = "path";

File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
    fileSaveDir.mkdir();
}

for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        //functionality to ormit non images

        String fileName = extractFileName(part);                                            

        part.write(savePath + "/" + fileName);

        String imagePath = savePath + "/" + fileName;

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {

            img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

            img = img.getSubimage(0, 0, 55, 55);

            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", fileSaveDir);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }                                               
}
```

Comment: Does part.write create a file? also where is this error located

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ImageIO.write((RenderedImage im, String formatName, File output));

```
Parameters:
im a RenderedImage to be written.
formatName a String containg the informal name of the format.
output a File to be written to.
```

As per documentation output file parameter is the file object where it would be image written where you have passed the parent directory file object.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!